# Pass a list of string to values in Azure App Service Settings

Tags: azure-devops

I have a list of string in my appsettings.json.

I an using Azure DevOps to deploy my code to Azure.

I am using the Release pipeline task "Azure App Sevice Settings".

I want to pass my list of strings to the above task parameter.

I have tried the below

```
[
{ "name": "test", "value": "["1", "2"]", "slotSetting": false }
]
```

The release pipeline is giving me the below error

```
Error: Application Settings object is not a valid JSON.
```

How do I pass list of string in the Azure App Service Settings task?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend you use a json validator to check whether your parameter value is good or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON string is not valid. Possibly you meant this, with the double-quotes escaped?

```
[
  { "name": "test", "value": "[\"1\", \"2\"]", "slotSetting": false }
]
```

Comment: Missed it. Thanks